# Session info error: chrome=111.0.5563.65, target window already closed in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, window

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC





#driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)


driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
path = "https://youtube.com"
driver.get(path)
#xpath for search box
x_path_for_box = "/html/body/ytd-app/div[1]/div/ytd-masthead/div[4]/div[2]/ytd-searchbox/form/div[1]/div[1]/input"
searching_point_box = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value=x_path_for_box)
#user manual input
search_word = input("Enter the search keyword: ")
searching_point_box.send_keys(search_word)
#xpath for search button
x_path_search_button= "/html/body/ytd-app/div[1]/div/ytd-masthead/div[4]/div[2]/ytd-searchbox/button"
searchButton = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value=x_path_search_button)
searchButton.click()


titles = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="video-title"]')

links = [] #for fetching video url

for i in titles:
    links.append(title.text)
    
print(links)

driver.close()
```

It gives me this error, I tried it even without closing the driver:
**NoSuchWindowException**: Message: no such window: target window already closed
from unknown error: web view not found
*(Session info: chrome=111.0.5563.65)*

Comment: this error can happen when running from a machine without a GUI or virtual display.  We need more info on the machine and what line throws the error.

Comment: I did it in Jupyter notebook and it throws an error when I generate through titles and want to add them to a list. Any possible solution to that?

Comment: `titles = driver.find_elements(By.ID, "video-title")` , I have exchanged it to this and now it is giving me an empty list.

Comment: Jupyter notebook has no GUI which may be the cause of the exception.  It's also fairly common for video sites to use the visibility API to decide whether to pause a video.  On top of that, ID is generally unique so that's probably the wrong locator for getting multiple elements.  (and the foreach is not using "i"...)  Also, driver.close() will close the current window/tab so the driver will need to be switched to an open window/tab to continue.  If you are trying to quit the driver, use driver.quit()